# What is the difference between a transactional client and transacted=true when using a JMS route in apache camel?

Tags: java, transactions, apache-camel, jms

I have a camel route where the from and to endpoints are jms.
I also have error handling ON.

Now, I wanna protect this message handling with a jms transaction handler. For that I have two options:

1. Either configure the route to use  as shown [here](http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html)
2. Or just configure the JMS endpoints to use `transacted=true` as shown [here](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)

What is the difference between two? Can anybody tell me which one is better and which to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://grokbase.com/t/camel/users/12b5mafwjc/transactional-client-vs-transacted-true-on-a-jms-route) (see Claus Ibsen's answer) `<transacted>` ensures the Camel processing runs inside a TX context. Where as without that the TX context is only for the broker (and only within the same unit of work from the same JMS session). Whereas `transacted=true` enables transactional consuming of messages. There's also an example there of where you would actually want to use `<transacted>` (consuming from http endpoint):

```
from jetty:http
transacted
to jms
to file
```

So if you're just passing messages from one JMS endpoint to another on sthe same broker, seems like you don't actually need a transacted route.

Comment: Just to add a bit more clarification - if you mark your route as `transacted` the transaction will wrap all other transactional resources that you use in your route - e.g. any database writes that you may do. If you use `transacted=true` the transaction will wrap only the JMS component of that single endpoint.